# Chaining promises when one of the promises is executed conditionally

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have two promises which are chained as below ,

`var promise1;`

```
var promise2 = promise1.then(function() {
```

});

Now I have a condition that promise1 will be executed based on a condition i.e

```
if(userid == 123) {
   promise1 should execute.
}
```

How do I chain promise1 and promise2   in this particular case where as I always need promise2 to be executed ?

Comment: I am assuming promise1 will return a second promise in the then function ?

Comment: Your promise1 is undefined in this case, so `promise1.then` won't work - can you give us a more complete example?

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but does `promise1` have to be run before `promise2`? - if not then you can just run `promise1` inside of the callback for `promise2`!

Comment: @MatthewCawley - Yes if should run before promise2, but only when userId is '123'.

Comment: does promise2 depends on promise1 result when promise1 need to execute?

Answer (score 1):

```
var promise1 = yourService.getSomthingAsync();
var promise2;
if(userid == 123){
    promise2 = promise1.then(function() {
    //do something
    var deferred = $q.defer(); // create new promise
    return deferred.$promise;
    }
} else {
  promise2 = $q.defer().$promise;
}

promise2.then(function(result){
    // do something else
}
```

I think you want to do this.
Notice that you will need to dependency inject $q

Comment: Thanks @ Arno, I will  give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would want the following :

```
var promise1 = asyncPromise();
var promise2 = asyncPromise2();

if(userid === 123){
   promise1
       .then(function(data){
            console.log(data); //data from resolving promise1
            return promise2; //returning a promise to chain
       })
       .then(function(data){ //chaining the promise returned from promise 1
            console.log(data);//data from resolving promise2.
       })
       .catch(function(err){//This catch block will be called for errors in both promise1 or promise 2.
           console.log(err)
       })
}
else{//If userid is not equal resolve promise2
    promise2
        .then(function(data){
             console.log(data);
        })
}
```